# aggregate function in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

i need a query which has aggregate function in include. i want to get count of ticket sell in each events

i tried code below

```
const data = await Items.paginate({
          page: offset.value,
          paginate: limit.value,
          where: itemType,
          include:[
            {model:ItemTypes},
            {model:ItemPayment,
              attributes: [[db.sequelize.fn('sum', db.sequelize.col('ItemPayments.numberOfTickets')), 'total']],
              group: ["ItemPayments.itemId"],

            }],
            raw:true
        });
```

but it gives me an error like below

`In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'Items.id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Answer (score 0):

Add `separate : true` and try to execute the query again

```
{   
    model:ItemPayment,
    attributes: [[db.sequelize.fn('sum', db.sequelize.col('ItemPayments.numberOfTickets')), 'total']],
    group: ["ItemPayments.itemId"],
    separate : true // <--------- HERE
}
```

Comment: not working here is the sql query
```sql:
          'SELECT `id`, sum(`ItemPayment`.`numberOfTickets`) AS `total`, `paymentId` FROM `ItemPayments` AS `ItemPayment` WHERE (`ItemPayment`.`paymentId` IN (29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 38, 39, 40, 41) AND `ItemPayment`.`itemId` = 1);' },```